# Failed Upload Video Screencast to Youtube

Tags: video, youtube, screencast, kazam

I have been migrate from Windows to Linux. I'll make video screencast and upload it on Youtube. I use Camtasia before, but it couldn't.
I get the alternative, Kazam. after I captured my screen and save video, I try to play the video and going normaly. But, if I try to upload it on Youtube, he said the video format is not supported. 
I visit the supported format page on youtube, and .mp4 should be accept.
I try to convert it using handbrake, but is not change anything, always not supported.
What can I do?

Sorry about bad English